# cast device discovery doesn't work for DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID

Tags: android, google-cast

was trying out the CastHelloText-android-master sample in the Google cast sdk.

it seems that I can't get device discovery to work if I change the MediaRouteSelector to look for CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID. The Cast button didn't appear. but if I change it to CastMediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_CAST, I'm able to get the button to show up.

The reason why I doing this is that I intend to use the default media receiver instead of deploying my own receiver.

I was wondering if there's a bug here. or I should just stick to CATEGORY_CAST for discovery. If you have a way to make it work, pls show me the way, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Those two static variables have different purposes.  According to the doc http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastMediaControlIntent.html:
`CATEGORY_CAST` - A control category for discovering Cast devices.
`DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID` - The application id for the Cast Default Media Receiver.

So, use `CATEGORY_CAST` for discovery and use the `DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID` in your `launchApplication` call.